# Docker в Docker

Tags: docker

Хочу запустить докер в докере. Делаю это в образе `golang:1.10.3`. Проделываю это ручками.

```
> apt-get update
> apt-get upgrade
> apt-get install docker
> docker
```

Получаю сообщение:

> bash: docker: command not found

Ошибок никаких не вываливалось. Почему такое происходит?

Comment: На официальной страничке смотрели документацию? https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/ Golang образ построен на Debian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое происходит потому что в репозитории ubuntu пакет docker - GUI приложение

установить сам сервис docker можно так:

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

//сс https://stackoverflow.com/a/30379382/4762530

Для такой цели лучше использовать официальный образ docker dind (docker in docker)
https://hub.docker.com/_/docker

Не забудьте что запускать этот образ следует с соответсвующими привилегиями

Comment: Вы сами пробовали это проделывать?

Comment: да, пробовал. А в чем вопрос?