# Docker в Docker в Docker

Tags: docker

У меня есть задача. Есть репки, в которых хранятся сервисы/воркеры. Их нужно деплоить и тестировать. Тестирование настроено в докере.

1. Поднимается докер с сервисом/воркером.
2. Поднимаются все зависимые контейнеры (psql, например и какой-нибудь почтовый сервер).
3. Поднимается контейнер с тестами и стреляет по сервису/воркеру.
4. Если постреляли и нашли ошибку, то докер с тестами завершается с кодом != 0. Умеем чекать это.
5. Если нет ошибки, то всё отлично. Выключаем все контейнеры и завершаем этап тестирования.

Хочу раннер поднимать в докере. Кроме того, хочется использовать docker-runner. Т.е. получается, что у меня возникает DockerInDockerInDocker. Далее, в докер-раннере оказывается ещё и несколько контейнеров: тесты, сервис/воркер, зависимые сервисы. Выглядит как жесть какая-то.

**Как решается такая проблема?**

Comment: следующий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/940944/178576) будет docker в docker в docker в docker?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ладно вам троллить. Я описал же вполне реальный кейс.

Comment: в вопросах тут встречаются вполне реальные кейсы типа «как мне сделать чат на vds, чтобы пользователи могли логиниться, писать сообщения и ставить друг другу лайки?». вы бы сосредоточились на какой-нибудь отдельной подзачае. например, что именно у вас не заработало при переходе от {docker}[2] к {docker}[3].

Comment: Посмотрите на этот репозиторий. Скорее всего этого вам будет достаточно https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind#can-i-run-docker-in-docker-in-docker

Comment: Этот пакет больше не поддерживается. Ему 4 года. Вряд ли он будет работать на новых версиях. И чуть ниже в описании репы указывается `If you read past this paragraph ... Then you're probably an archaeologist, a masochist, or both.` и советуют использовать официальную репу docker:dind. Но картинка у них прикольная